# Create custom list in SPServices

Tags: jquery, spservices

Is there a way to create a new custom list with SPServices? There are ways to create new list items, but I couldn't find a way to create a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SPServices wraps the `Lists` web service:

https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists

Which includes `AddList`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.addlist.aspx

Once the list is created, you would use `UpdateList` to add fields or modify other properties:

https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UpdateList&referringTitle=Lists

In my opinion (if you are using at least SP2010), list creation via JSOM is simpler than SPServices:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410509%28v=office.14%29.aspx